# Format number in Excel to align decimals but also remove decimal point optionally based on size of number

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, cell-format, rounding

I'd like to create a publishable data table in Excel. Numbers may range from `0.010` to `1,000`. I need to have similar significant figures and aligned decimal points. This is what I am looking for as display:

```
0.131 -> 0.1310

1.3 -> 1.300

130 -> 130.0

13.1 -> 13.10

1300 -> 1,300
```

For the `1300`, I got a decimal to not be on the end (e.g. `1,300.`) using the below strategy. But this does not align the over `1000` with the other decimal point areas.

```
    0.1582

    1.582

   15.82

  158.2

1,582
```

This is what I have used:
Format cell to be `0.????`. Then also used Conditional Formatting Rule of:

Cell Value greater than or equal to `1000`
<kbd>Format</kbd> -> <kbd>Custom</kbd> -> `###,###`

It also needs to keep sig figs at `4`, which it is set at whatever number you type in to begin with. I would like this to be automatic.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excel may not be the right tool for this (it's not very good for layout work). Any good layout software, even MS Word has built in functionality for this

Comment: Setting multiple overlapping conditional formatting on the same column is an option? If yes, you can easily do it that way.

Comment: Like this https://i.imgur.com/uYkLvU1.png

Comment: I use MS Word originally with these, but I want also want the functionality to directly make graphs out of the data as well. So using Excel to do both is the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overlay two techniques. First, using >value ranges in your number formatting, and then (because you need more than three formats), a conditional format rule to apply a second format with similar approach.
For the main number format, use this:

```
[>9.999]00.00_0_0;[>0.999]0.000_0;0.0000
```

This translates as:

> For numbers greater than 9.999, use a format which always has two
> digits after the decimal point, then pad with spaces for the "missing"
> zeroes; then for numbers >0.999 (but less than 10, because of the
> order of precedence from left to right), apply a similar thing one
> place to the right; "otherwise" show four decimal places with a
> leading zero before the decimal point.

These ranges effectively replace the default breakdown of a number format into positive, negative and zero sections.

Now apply a conditional format rule to the data range, configured for cells with values "greater than or equal to" 100 and apply this number format:

```
[>999.999]0,000_._0_0_0_0;###.0_0_0_0
```

Note just two sections here: >999.999 and "otherwise", because we already know this only applies to numbers >=100

If your numbers are actually much more precise (ie have lots more decimals) then you might need more 9's after the decimal in the formats to avoid issues, eg use >999.999999

Comment: Is there any way to add to this a spacing away from the very align right justification at least one space? With center alignment of the cell, it loses the decimal alignment aspect.

Comment: All those underscores just mean "add a space the width of the following character". You could add another _0 or maybe an _. (underscore period) to add a medium or tiny amount of space on the right. Add the same to all of the formats so they continue to line up

Answer (score 0):

To format a number in Excel to align decimals but also optionally remove the decimal point based on the size of the number, you can use a custom number format.

Here's how to do it:

Select the range of cells you want to format.

Right-click and select "Format Cells".

In the "Format Cells" dialog box, select "Number" under the "Number" tab.

Under "Category", select "Custom".

In the "Type" box, enter the following custom number format:

0.00,"K";[>=1000]0.00,,"M";[>=1000000]0.00,,,"B";

This number format will display two decimal places for numbers less than 1000, but remove the decimal point for numbers greater than 1000 and add a letter to indicate thousand, million, or billion.

Click OK to apply the custom number format to the selected range of cells.

[I hope this helps! You can also check out this link for more information](https://www.formation-excel.be/accompagnement-mise-a-niveau?sa=sa00850324233b762d542953be0d45d3686ef08e2e)